# Not filling full column height in ColumnLayout

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I have a simple QML design that consists of 2 components side by side then another component (named HUD) below that. The HUD should fill the remaining height but instead it leaves a gap.

How can I make HUD fill all the available width. I am trying to achieve the 2nd image.

[image]

[image]

```
Page {
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height

    title: qsTr("Home")

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        RowLayout {
            Layout.fillWidth: true;

            StatusBar {
                width: parent.width * 0.5;
                height: parent.height * 0.1
                anchors.left: parent.left;
            }

            MenuBar {
                width: parent.width * 0.5;
                height: parent.height * 0.1
                anchors.right: parent.right;
            }
        }

        // The below should fill the remaining height but its not?
        HUD {
            Layout.fillWidth: true;
            Layout.fillHeight: true;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `Layout.fillHeight: false` to your RowLayout, and you should be good to go.
By default, for Layouts, Layout.fillHeight and Layout.fillWidth are true.

```
    RowLayout {
        Layout.fillWidth: true;
        Layout.fillHeight: false;

        StatusBar {
            width: parent.width * 0.5;
            height: parent.height * 0.1
            anchors.left: parent.left;
        }

        MenuBar {
            width: parent.width * 0.5;
            height: parent.height * 0.1
            anchors.right: parent.right;
        }
    }
```